# deny symfony credentials in security.yml

Tags: symfony1

is possible to deny a credential in security.yml?

For example:

```
default:

  is_secure: true
  credentials: admin
```

(i want that user have not the admin credential)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. All you can do is add all the other credentials to the security file with a `OR` connector or add some php code in the `actions.class.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is extending the `sfBasicSecurityUser` class, overriding the `hasCredential()` method to handle it (for example by adding a `!` before the given credential). This is what the security filter uses to check if the user may access the requested action.
Then edit your app's `myUser` class to extend this new class, and voila.